# Почему индикатор о новом участнике говорит лишь о дружелюбии к новичкам?

Tags: обсуждение, новые-участники, индикатор-новичка

> [image: индикатор новичка]

а к  старым не надо быть дружелюбным?:)

Comment: @СергейВалерьевич :)

Comment: Из того, что к новым надо быть дружелюбным, не следует, что к старым не надо. Так что не вижу проблемы в этой фразе

Comment: Почему тогда такая плашка есть только у новых?

Comment: @СергейВалерьевич потому что "новым участником" может быть только новый :)

Comment: И что? Нужно только заменить одно слово, а гарри будет приятно

Comment: @СергейВалерьевич добавить "старый участник" остальным? :) В этом нет смысла, потому что если у тебя нет плашки "новый участник", то ты автоматически считаешься старым

Comment: Добавить, что нужно быть дружелюбным

Comment: @СергейВалерьевич возможно, есть смысл добавить про дружелюбность куда-то, но не под каждым ником. Прозрачным шрифтом в поле для написания комментария, например. Но это надо уже новый вопрос задавать

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Тут такое совпадение. Буквально через час после Вашего вопроса задали другой: [Отношение к новичкам](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10683/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC). Он в какой-то мере содержит один из доводов в пользу того чтобы плашка висела у новых участников:

> А то ruSo теряет так участников. Он просто зайдет, посмотрит, его вопрос почему-то удалили, решит, что ruSo фигня.

Текст на плашке нового участника не означает, что старым участникам можно хамить. Просто от старых участников ожидается что они знают правила сайта и особенности его работы: как закрываются вопросы, как их можно переоткрыть, кто ставит минуса, какие вопросы приветствуются, а какие нет.

Индикатор новичка напоминает что новому участнику по-возможности нужно объяснять что он делает неправильно перед тем как предъявлять к нему претензии. Stack Overflow таким образом пытаются избежать ситуации когда человек приходит на сайт с вопросом, в ответ получает охапку минусов и странных комментариев со ссылками на какую-то мету, обижается, уходит с сайта и пишет всем своим подписчикам в Twitter, что у нас тут сборище социопатов. Индикатор ввели как часть инициативы [Welcome Wagon](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/07/10/welcome-wagon-classifying-comments-on-stack-overflow/), начатой в 2018-м году.

Эффективность индикатора новичка весьма неочевидна и текст, наверное, можно улучшить, но какая-никакая мотивация за ним прослеживается.

Answer (score 6):

Есть мнение, что старожилы негативно относятся к новичкам. Компания провела анализ данных и решила таким образом напоминать участникам, что все мы когда-то были новичками.

Из этой фразы не следует, что "не надо быть дружелюбным со старыми участниками".

Comment: я не говорю что это надо убрать, просто такая штука есть только у новых)