# Отношение к новичкам

Tags: обсуждение, новички

Если новичок что-то нарушил (сделал код ссылкой допустим, как вот [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1158845/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE-grid%D1%8B) вопрос) то не надо мне кажется закрывать его и удалять. Я бы просто исправил (кстати я это сделал) и объяснить ему это. А то ruSo  теряет так участников. Он просто зайдет, посмотрит, его вопрос почему-то удалили, решит, что ruSo фигня.

Comment: Лучше сказать об исправлении в комментариях, потому что если самому отредактировать, то есть шанс, что следующий вопрос будет таким же. Этот шанс меньше при самостоятельном исправлении вопроса. Да и переходить по неизвестным ссылкам не лучшая идея

Comment: О каком удалённом сообщении речь?

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik о том, который сначала заминусили, потом закрыли, а через некоторое время его дух грохнул :) Потом новичок заходит через 3 месяца, а вопрос тю-тю. Ну его, этот ruSO, подумает он, пойду пиво пить с друзьями, и правильно сделает. В программировании нужна настойчивость!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Звучит вполне разумно. Если вопрос можно легко и быстро исправить, то почему бы этого и не сделать. И тут достаточно часто правят вопросы новичков. Другое дело что это не всегда так просто.

Автор указанного вопроса подготовил короткий пример кода, единственная ошибка что выложил его на codepen, а не здесь. Если бы автор дал ссылку на репозиторий git с сотней файлов, то найти релевантный код было бы сложнее. А если бы автор вообще никакой код не выложил бы, то никто, кроме него, не смог бы исправить этот вопрос.

В таких случаях можно только попросить автора исправить вопрос в комментариях. А если не исправит, то придется «закрывать и удалять», что еще делать. Есть еще случаи когда вопрос изначально так плох, что сложно представить, что его можно исправить, по таким сразу голосуют за закрытие.

Ну и, как уже написал [@dIm0n](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/398802/dim0n) в комментариях, в целях обучения имеет смысл просить новичка исправить вопрос самому. Так он познакомится с инструментами правки и лучше запомнит правила сайта. Впрочем, граница между «исправить самому» и «просить автора» довольно эфемерна. На сайте есть как участники, готовые переписывать чужие вопросы целиком, так и участники, которые предпочитают чтобы автор как можно больше говорил сам за себя.

### Немного формализма

В Вашем вопросе видится какая-то претензия к сообществу. Когда его прочитал сложилось ощущение что вопрос поспешно/несправедливо закрыли и удалили. Но оказалось, что вопрос открыт, его никто не закрывал, и, уж тем более, не удалял . Более того, судя по его [истории](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1158845/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries) никто и не голосовал за закрытие вопроса.

Может Вы путаете голоса за закрытие с голосами против (минусами)? Заминусованный вопрос не закрыт — на него можно получать ответы. А минусы четко показывают автору наличие проблемы.

Для закрытия вопроса нужно пять голосов от участников с [3000 репутации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions). Участников у нас немного и вопросы обычно закрываются медленно. И если вопрос закроют, то автор получит уведомление что его вопрос можно исправить и переоткрыть.

Удаляются же вопросы, как правило, автоматически, при этом это давно закрытые вопросы без исправлений и с отрицательным рейтингом.

### Ситуация с вопросом

Что имеем в итоге по вопросу:

- автор задает его, выкладывая код на постороннем ресурсе;
- через 7 минут в комментарии пишут что нужно исправить:

[image: комментарий]

- еще через 6 минут пользователь правит орфографические ошибки в вопросе за автора;
- еще через 6 минут, на вопрос дают ответ;
- где-то в этом промежутке вопросу ставят два минуса (если больше, то значит кто-то забрал свои обратно);
- еще через минуту Вы вставляете код в вопрос;
- еще через 3 минуты автор принимает Вашу правку;
- в комментариях автор обещает в дальнейшем учитывать, что код надо публиковать здесь;
- вопрос получает два плюса, автор +18 к репутации.

По-моему тут все получилось хорошо. Даже если бы вопрос не исправили, у автора было бы достаточно времени чтобы исправить вопрос самому. Не, то что Вы код скопировали это хорошо, то что автору объяснили как его оформлять — еще лучше. Но притеснения новичка в этом конкретном вопросе я не вижу.